# Magento creating custom session in admin side is not working

Tags: magento, session-cookies

I have created a custom session in admin side of magento below is my code

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("default");
$userId_new = 'final_value';

Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setSessionVariable($userId_new);
```

I cant access the created session variable on the other page of the admin side below is the code to get the created session variable

```
echo $final_value = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setSessionVariable($userId_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

to access you would have use the getter magic method 

`echo $final_value = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getSessionVariable()`

or could access it from the data array 

`echo $final_value = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                   ->getData('session_variable')`

Comment: I tried both method not working for me any other solution

Comment: you would have to give more info about what you are trying to accomplish to get a better picture if the issue